# Upload file via SFTP with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sftp, pysftp

I wrote a simple code to upload a file to a SFTP server in Python. I am using Python 2.7.

```
import pysftp

srv = pysftp.Connection(host="www.destination.com", username="root",
password="password",log="./temp/pysftp.log")

srv.cd('public') #chdir to public
srv.put('C:\Users\XXX\Dropbox\test.txt') #upload file to nodejs/

# Closes the connection
srv.close()
```

The file did not appear on the server. However, no error message appeared. What is wrong with the code?

I have enabled logging. I discovered that the file is uploaded to the root folder and not under `public` folder. Seems like `srv.cd('public')` did not work.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question.

```
import pysftp

srv = pysftp.Connection(host="www.destination.com", username="root",
password="password",log="./temp/pysftp.log")

with srv.cd('public'): #chdir to public
    srv.put('C:\Users\XXX\Dropbox\test.txt') #upload file to nodejs/

# Closes the connection
srv.close()
```

Put the `srv.put` inside with `srv.cd`

Comment: Pysftp is dead. Better use Paramiko. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33751854/850848#73432631).

Answer (score 22):

Do not use pysftp it's dead. Use Paramiko directly. See also [pysftp vs. Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48434941/850848).

---

The code with Paramiko will be pretty much the same, except for the initialization part.

```
import paramiko
 
with paramiko.SSHClient() as ssh:
    ssh.load_system_host_keys()
    ssh.connect(host, username=username, password=password)
 
    sftp = ssh.open_sftp()

    sftp.chdir('public')
    sftp.put('C:\Users\XXX\Dropbox\test.txt', 'test.txt')
```

---

To answer the literal OP's question: the key point here is that [pysftp `Connection.cd`](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pysftp.html#pysftp.Connection.cd) works as a context manager (so its effect is discarded without `with` statement), while [Paramiko `SFTPClient.chdir`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.chdir) does not.

Answer (score 9):

```
import pysftp

with pysftp.Connection(host="www.destination.com", username="root",
password="password",log="./temp/pysftp.log") as sftp:

  sftp.cwd('/root/public')  # The full path
  sftp.put('C:\Users\XXX\Dropbox\test.txt')  # Upload the file
```

No `sftp.close()` is needed, because the connection is closed automatically at the end of the with-block

I did a minor change with `cd` to `cwd`

Syntax -

```
# sftp.put('/my/local/filename')  # upload file to public/ on remote
# sftp.get('remote_file')         # get a remote file
```

Comment: The "minor change" of `cd` to `cwd` it the actual fix. The `cd` works as a context manager, while `cwd` does not.