# Python: How to upload a file to SFTP via zip stream

Tags: python, stream, zip

I saw an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33752662/1129332) how to upload a file to SFTP

```
import pysftp

srv = pysftp.Connection(host="www.destination.com", username="root",
password="password",log="./temp/pysftp.log")

with srv.cd('public'): #chdir to public
    srv.put('C:\Users\XXX\Dropbox\test.txt') #upload file to nodejs/

# Closes the connection
srv.close()
```

But how can I upload and zip it at the same time? To be clear I don't want to zip it and then upload it, I want to make it at the same time using zipped stream.

Comment: You can use the `putfo()` method instead of `put()` and pass in a ZIP file instance (`zipfile.ZipFile`) that is backed by a `io.StringIO` object.

Comment: Can you provide a full example please where you take my sample.txt file and upload it to sample.zip file to SFTP

Answer (score 1):

To stream a file via pysftp do the following:

```
import pysftp
import io

with io.StringIO("hello world!\r\n") as stream:
    with pysftp.Connection("sftp.mywebsite.com", username="myuser", password="mypassword") as sftp:
        with sftp.cd("myhome/uploads"):
            sftp.putfo(stream, "hello.txt", confirm=False)
```

Setting `confirm` to `False` will tell pysftp **NOT** to verify the length of the file.  If you need to verify the length of the file with `file_size` in pysftp then you will need to say `len(secondstream.read())` and duplicate the stream since reading consumes the stream from memory meaning no data will be written.